# Shadow not being applied if setting corner radius

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to add corner radius to bottmLeft and bottomRight corner and also to add shadow to it. But for some reason if I add those corner radiuses the shadow disappears. What causes this?

This is what I do:

I Have extension:

```
extension UIView {
    func roundCorners(_ corners: UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat) {
        self.layoutIfNeeded()
        let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
        let mask = CAShapeLayer()
        mask.path = path.cgPath
        self.layer.mask = mask
    }
}
```

Apply corners:

`myView.roundCorners([.bottomLeft, .bottomRight], radius: 35`)

Add shadow extension:

```
func addShadow(offset: CGSize, color: UIColor, radius: CGFloat, opacity: Float) {
    let layer = self.layer
    layer.masksToBounds = false
    layer.shadowOffset = offset
    layer.shadowColor = color.cgColor
    layer.shadowRadius = radius
    layer.shadowOpacity = opacity
    layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath.init(roundedRect: layer.bounds, cornerRadius: layer.cornerRadius).cgPath

    let backgroundCGColor = self.backgroundColor?.cgColor
    self.backgroundColor = nil
    layer.backgroundColor =  backgroundCGColor
}
```

And add shadow:

```
myView.addShadow(offset: CGSize.init(width: 0.0, height: 10.0) , color: UIColor.blue, radius: 35.0, opacity: 1.0)
```

Why the shadow disappears after adding the rounded corners?

Comment: try to add self.clipsToBounds = false

Answer (score 0):

myView.layer.**shadowPath** needs to be initialized with a UIBezierPath. Just give it the same frame and bounds as myView.